# Why is '1,4p' outputing all the lines instead of just the first four?

Tags: sed

I have a text file called "list" which contains some random words:

```
he
she
we
his
her
with
his this this -- this
this
```

I ran this sed command:

```
sed '1,4p' list
```

What I thought this sed command was going to do was list the first 4 words in this file, so I though the output would be:

```
he
she
we
his
```

But instead the output was this:

```
he
he
she
she
we
we
his
his
her
with
his this this -- this
this
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong or why the output is different?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are forgetting that the *default action* of sed is to print each pattern space (line) - so suppress the default behaviour you need to add the `-n` switch

```
sed -n '1,4p' list
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
sed -n 1,4p list
```

or this:

```
sed '1,4!d' list
```

More [examples](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.de/2008/03/using-sed-to-extract-lines-in-text-file.html)

Comment: Or `sed 4q list` or `head -n4 list`

Answer (score 1):

### What it does in general

Your script expression will be executed on each line in turn.

To execute expressions on a line, `sed` will first copy it to the **pattern space**.
Then, all expressions are executed, each using the pattern space as input, and writing the result back to the pattern space.

So normally, when the steps of work for the line are done, we have a final string in the pattern space. In most cases, we want just that as output, for example after it was changed by several `s//` commands.
Because it is often useful, `sed` prints the final pattern space, as if it would append a `p` expression.

You can already see that this causes the output of your command.

- The line is put into the pattern space
- Your script prints the pattern space for four matching lines using `p`
- It does not update the pattern space when it finishes.
- As it's already at the end of the list of expressions,
  the pattern space is printed, because it's done by default

Note it is outputting "all the lines **and** the first four" - as opposed to "all the lines instead of just the first four".

So, of the repeated lines, the first of each is what you printed, and the second is what is printed by default.

The `sed` option `-n` (`--quiet`) switches of the default of printing the pattern space:

```
sed -n 1,4p list
```

To see what your original command is doing, we can make both kinds of lines look differently: we change the pattern space before printng it at the end by prefixing it with `-` :

```
$ sed -e '1,4p' -e 's/^/- /'  list
he
- he
she
- she
we
- we
his
- his
- her
- with
- his this this -- this
- this
```

(The `-e` options are needed to supply multiple expressions. 's/^/- /' replaces nothing at the start of line by `-` .)